# Pyglet walking animation. Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'

Tags: python, sprite, runtime-error, pyglet

This code displays the image `assassin1.png` on a black background. The idea is that as soon as I press the `<right-direction>` key the character should move and display an animation using `assassin2.png` and `assassin3.png`. I have been able to move the character and display the animation succesfully, just not the two at the same time.

The following code runs as long as I don't press the `<right direction>` key:

```
import pyglet

def sprite_type(type_ = "standing"):
    if type_ == "moving-forward":
        moving_forward_image_list = [pyglet.image.load('assassin2.png'), pyglet.image.load('assassin3.png')]
        moving_forward_animation = pyglet.image.Animation.from_image_sequence(moving_forward_image_list, 0.3) 
        return moving_forward_animation
    if type_ == "standing":
        standing_animation = pyglet.image.load("assassin1.png")
        return standing_animation

class Assassin(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, batch, img):
        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, img, x = 50, y = 30)

    def stand(self, batch, img):
        self.batch = batch
        self.img = img

    def move(self, batch, img):
        self.batch = batch
        self.img = img      

class Game(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        pyglet.window.Window.__init__(self, width = 315, height = 220)
        self.batch_draw = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.player = Assassin(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type())
        self.fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()
        self.keys_held = []      
        self.schedule = pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(func = self.update, interval = 1/60.) 

    def on_draw(self): 
        self.clear()         
        self.fps_display.draw()
        self.batch_draw.draw()
        self.player.draw()  

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        self.keys_held.append(symbol)
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.RIGHT:
            self.player = self.player.move(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type("moving-forward"))
            print "The 'RIGHT' key was pressed"

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        self.keys_held.pop(self.keys_held.index(symbol))
        self.player = self.player.stand(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type("standing"))

    def update(self, interval):
        if pyglet.window.key.RIGHT in self.keys_held:
            self.player.x += 50 * interval

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Game()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

As soon as I press the `<right-direction>` key the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ircex.py", line 55, in <module>
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/app/__init__.py", line 264, in run
    EventLoop().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/app/xlib.py", line 93, in run
    sleep_time = self.idle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/app/__init__.py", line 193, in idle
    window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1219, in dispatch_event
    EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 349, in dispatch_event
    return getattr(self, event_type)(*args)
  File "pyglet-walk.py", line 37, in on_draw
    self.player.draw()  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the `move()` method returns `None`:

```
class Assassin(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    (...)


    def move(self, batch, img):
        self.batch = batch
        self.img = img
```

Then in the line below you set `self.player` to return value of `player.move()`, which is `None`:

```
self.player = self.player.move(batch = self.batch_draw, img = sprite_type("moving-forward"))
```

Which leads to `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'draw'`, because `self.player` is `None` and you try to call `draw()` on it.

Comment: I put `return self` at the end of the `move` and `stand`method. Now this doesn't produce a runtime error when pressing the `<right-direction>` key. But it does produce the same error when releasing the key and the `stand` method is called. Also, when the character is moving to the right it just shows the standing animation again. Any ideas?

Comment: The same thing with `stand()` method - it returns `None`!

Comment: There was still another editor running in the background with the same file, I just kept running that. I'm sorry! Now the errors are gone. But when I press the `<right-direction button>` the walking animation still doesn't show. Only the standing animation shows. Do you know why?

Comment: Dear Secator, I voted your answer as the answer to my question because it answers the title. It is not what I wanted but that is because I posed the wrong question. Could you please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308382/pyglet-changing-the-image-of-a-sprite-instance-when-pressing-a-button) SO thread? I simplified the example and added the changes.

Comment: Np, I thought you were mad at me because I couldn't find it myself.